# Error in `ode45` matlab

Tags: matlab, ode, matlab-deployment, differential-equations

The main function of `ode` is given as follows.

```
function dxdt = state( t,x,vgth,vgval1,vgval2)
vgval=vgval1+vgval2;
p=1;
k=10^0.7;
window1=1-((2*x)-1).^(2*p); 
dxdt=k*(vgval-vgth+1.2)*window1;  
end
```

The Script is given below.

```
step=0.01;
t = 0:step:10;
f=4*0.157;
vgate1= @(t) abs(5*sin(2*f*t)).*heaviside(5-t);
vgate2=@(t) -abs(5*sin(2*f*t)).*heaviside(t-5);
```

The Function call part is as follows.

```
x0=0.01;
vgth=1.9;
[t,x] = ode45(@(t,x) state1 (t,x,vgth,vgate1(t),vgate2(t)), t, x0);
plot(t,x)
```

**Issue**
 It gives me error when I use the negative sign with `vgate2` .
It works fine If i remove the negative sign of `vgate2`.

**Desired Result**
I want my plot with a negative sign in `vgate2`.Actually I want to use two positive sine pulses and two negative sign pulses.That is why I have used negative value of `vgate2`.

Comment: What is the output of `state1`? Can you add the error message you get in your post?

Comment: Can you try to explicitly integrate to t=5 and then restart? Splice after that the solutions together. Non-smooth events are bad for the step-size adaptor, jumps are the worst of them.

Comment: @BillBokeey `x` is the output of `state1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ODE integrators of order `p` expect the differential equation to be `p+2` times continuously differentiable with decent sized derivatives.

Any deviation from that is seen as "stiffness" by step-size adaptation strategies, and reacted to by increasingly violent reductions in step-size. Any kink or jump in the lower derivatives is seen as similar to wild oscillations in the higher derivative, throwing the step-size adaptor for a loop.

However, if the integration is stopped directly at an event and then restarted using the values there as initial values, the integrator does not "see" the event, and thus has no need to react to it.